# Am I allowed to ask a duplicate if the existing question does not answer my queries?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I was asked a question in an interview about overriding static methods in java. I searched for some questions in stackoverflow and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods/2223803#2223803), but it didn't solve all my queries.

Therefore I was thinking of posting another question, but scared to get down votes. What should I do?

Comment: If the answer does not answer your question then it is no duplicate.

Ask very specifically  what you want to know and you will be fine.

Comment: You could refer the original question in your question and state what's the difference between that and what currently(what you want to know) which is not answered. That would clearly show that you've done some research about your problem before asking it. That way it would not be a duplicate, as its not asking the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A question is put "on hold" (or closed) when it is **exact** duplicate - that is, it adds no new information over the old one.

This is clearly not your case: you have a significant gap you wish to fill in that respect.  So (as [R.J](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/216721/r-j) suggests in his [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206933/am-i-allowed-to-ask-a-duplicate-if-the-existing-question-does-not-answer-my-quer#comment657758_206933)), ask your question, put a link to the other questions you have already found, and provide a **clear** explanation as to what you are missing in those answers and you wish to know. Doing so will clearly mark your question as **not** an "exact duplicate" and therefore a quality SO question.

Good luck!

Comment: Just one comment, questions marked as duplicate are not put on hold but closed instantly as duplicates. It says "marked as duplicate" in the banner and "duplicate" in the title. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thanks for this clarification.